# How to detect the load event of iframe which is inside a html scope from the outside of iframe(parent html)

Tags: iframe, load, prototypejs

a few notes:

- 1.i can not modify the iframe content to add the onload= function
- 2.the iframe has an id.
- 3.the iframe has no callback to its parent html page.
- 4.I use the prototype ,not jquery, for some old reasons.

  i wanna do something when the iframe load finished.
  but, i have tried the

  document.observe('dom:loaded',function()
  {

  ```
      alert($('iframe-id'));  >> **IS NULL**
  ```

  })

and

```
Event.observe(window,'load',function(){..
alert($('iframe-id'));  >> **IS NULL STILL**

...})
```

Did i miss some methods in prototype or javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: But the iframe is on the same domain?

Comment: yes,actually it is a wysiwyg editor.